# Using server-side javascript in classic asp: what's wrong with "this"?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, jscript

> similar: [Inserting objects into global scope in classic ASP / Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629993/inserting-objects-into-global-scope-in-classic-asp-javascript)

---

Trying to get started with using javascript in classic ASP.  Seem to be some "gotchas" with this though: can anyone with some experience in this tell me what's up with the "Blah2" code ?  Seems like it "should" work but there seems to be a problem with my use of "this"...

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">

 var Blah = {};
 Blah.w = function(s){Response.write(s);}

 Blah.w('hello'); //this works...


 var Blah2 = function(){
     this.w = function(s){Response.write(s);} 
     //line above gives 'Object doesn't support this property or method'
     return this;
 }();

 Blah2.w('hello');

</script>
```

Thanks for any pointers

Tim

Comment: @Sebastian: Classic ASP allowed you to use either VBScript or JavaScript on the server-side.

Comment: you probably realize this, but believe it or not, there are some who don't - "Classic" ASP shouldn't be used unless you have no choice.

Comment: @John: Yes, I know that by now I should be up to speed with asp.net (after all, it's at least 10 years old at this point).  However, I'm pretty familiar with classic ASP, have a quick project to push out, and thought I'd at least try to learn something new (old?) by switching from server-side vbscript to j(ava)script, to brush up on a bit of JSON.

Comment: `runat="server"` is for asp.net, not classic asp. which were you really using?

Comment: @Joel: I was really using classic ASP. Classic ASP also uses runat=server...

Comment: It's funny how many people insist Classic ASP can't run javascript server-side...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parens around your function

```
var Blah2 = (function(){
    this.w = function(s){Response.write(s);} 
    //line above gives 'Object doesn't support this property or method'
    return this;
}());
```

Also, `this.w` isn't doing what you want.  `this` is actually pointing to the global object right there.  You want:

```
var Blah2 = (function(){
    return {w : function(s){ Response.write(s); }};
}());
```

Or

```
bar Blah2 = new (function(){
   ...
```

Comment: Someone else please jump in and correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure "this" in the context I used it refers to the function Blah2, not to the global object...  At least, that's how it works in a browser: what I'm not clear about is why it doesn't work in this context.  Unless you're specifically saying *in server-side ASP* it works as you describe ?

Comment: Nope, not unless you create an object with `new`.  Run this in any browser if you don't believe me: `function blah(){ alert(this === window); } blah()`.  Function calls don't, by themselves, have `this` set.

Comment: I should add that your second example (similar to my first) *does* work. I'm really just trying to find out why "this" seems to be a problem in this context.

Comment: thanks for correcting me: I just read another SO question addressing this and headed back here to eat my words.

Comment: javascript is **case sensitive**, folks! Don't forget this when mixing vbscript and javascript server-side.